# SSIS avoid crashing when issue with data constrain

Tags: ssis

Each time when I run ssis packages and at least one row can not be inserter due some errors like duplicate or null into not null column, the package crashes and all data is roll back.

Is this possible to even if there are errors, insert all the rest correct data ?

Comment: You'll need to weed out the bad data. That is all part of an ETL!  A derived column can be used to change Null values to zero or blank. A conditional split could be used to filter unwanted null records. A lookup to the destination table prior to the insert of a new record could be used to divert duplicate records.

Answer (score 1):

No, we cant do that when an error occurred in a package everything will be rollback.

But if you want the commit the tasks which ran successfully even though the package fails at any step.

we have transaction in properties of package when you set it to true then the package will be committed automatically(for only tasks which ran successfully) and when it run for next time it will start from the place where it got error.

but we cant load the half half data in single task